# Java ip address proxy

Tags: java, proxy, ip, vpn

I have openVPN Connect configured on a vista laptop, so that connecting with a web browser allows the computer to change its ip address. What are the steps necessary to allow the following networking code in java to use this new ip address:

```
  import java.net.*;

  public class A
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
       InetAddress kj=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
       System.out.println(kj.getHostAddress());


     }

 }
```

running ipconfig from command prompt:
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection  2:

connection-specific dns suffix : 
Link-local IPv6 Addres....:fe80::adde(ect...)
IPv4 Address........(5.5.32.x)
Subnet Mask....(255.255.0.0)
Default Gateway.....:

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
Connection-specific DNS suffic .: (ect...)
Link-local IPv6 Address ...: fe80::8177:a91b:(ec...)
IPv4 Address......:(76.181.x.x)
Subnet Mask.....:255.255.224.0
Default Gateway....(some ip different than the ipv4 address above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the IP addresses of the local machine this way:

```
String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
InetAddress addrs[] = InetAddress.getAllByName(hostName);
```

You will need a way of determining which of the IP addresses are for the VPN. Typically a VPN will give you a known range of addresses (e.g. 10.19.10.x) which you can detect.

If you connect to the VPN, then from a command line run **ipconfig**, pasting the output here, we may be able to help you determine the pattern to match.

Comment: And once i see the vpn pattern where would i use it, to get the code above to print out the ipv4 address from Local Area Connection 2 above?

Comment: You should have multiple IP addresses bound from your **ipconfig** output, it's the IPv4 ones you're interested in - for each v4 IP, determine what it's for (your LAN, localhost, VPN etc). When you know what your VPN IPs are likely to be (e.g. 10.x.x.x) you can iterate over the **addrs[]** in my answer, looking for an InetAddress which matches.

Comment: and what about using that vpn address for URLConnection in java, is this possible?

Comment: Depends what you're wanting to do - I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with the information, so I can't really comment on whether the data is relevant. However, I believe the above is the answer to your question.

Comment: ok thanks, i want to be able to see the vpn address if i were to do the following: HttpURLConnection x=(HttpURLConnection)new URL("google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&h1=en&site=&source=hp&q=ip%20address&btnG=Search").openConnection(); And then open an iput stream, read it in, and see one of the vpn addresses in the page, after the html: "Your public IP address is ".