# How to get the vpn ip address java

Tags: java, ip, vpn, inetaddress

How to get the original IP address of a machine behind a VPN ?

I am developing a simple application that can show the real IP address and the VPN given the IP address. I want to know that when I send a request to server then does the server sees the real IP or the vpn IP ?

Comment: You can refer this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772318/java-ip-address-proxy

Comment: i have read this . can you please tell me that when i send a request the then do server get the real ip or changed ip (VPN)?